# MUI permanent drawer Spacing issues

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I following this for coding: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#api

but i found there has a little bug, and i cannot fix it, I hardly modified the style of muidrawer the problem should not be related to other parts, but I don't know how to change the style of sidebar to fix it, please help me.

there is code:

Siderbar

```
import {Box, CSSObject, Divider, IconButton, Link, List, ListItem, ListItemButton,
    ListItemIcon,
    ListItemText, Stack, styled, Typography} from "@mui/material";
import {useState} from "react";
import MuiDrawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import {Link as RouterLink} from "react-router-dom";
import CloudCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CloudCircle';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import LiveHelpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LiveHelp';
import SettingsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
import PaymentIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Payment';
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";

const menus = {
    user_menu: [
        {
            header: "Dashboard",
            link: "/dashboard",
            icon: <CloudCircleIcon/>,
        },
        {
            header: "Subscribes",
            link: "/dashboard/subscribe",
            icon: <PaymentIcon/>,
        },
    ],
    sys_menu: [
        {
            header: "FAQs",
            link: "/dashboard/faqs",
            icon: <LiveHelpIcon/>,
        },
        {
            header: "Settings",
            link: "/dashboard/setting",
            icon: <SettingsIcon/>,
        },
    ],
};
const sidebarWidth: number = 240;

const openSidebar = (theme: any): CSSObject => ({
    width: sidebarWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: "hidden",
});
const closeSidebar = (theme: any): CSSObject => ({
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    overflowX: "hidden",
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
    },
});

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, {shouldForwardProp: (prop: any) => prop !== "open"})(({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: sidebarWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    ...(open && {
        ...openSidebar(theme),
        "& .MuiDrawer-paper": openSidebar(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
        ...closeSidebar(theme),
        "& .MuiDrawer-paper": closeSidebar(theme),
    }),
}));
export const SideBar = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
    return (
        <Box display="flex">
            <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
                <Box
                    display="flex"
                    justifyContent={open ? "space-between" : "center"}
                    alignItems="center"
                    p={1}
                >
                    <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ display: open ? "flex" : "none" }}>
                        NM Manage
                    </Typography>
                    <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                        {open? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <MenuIcon /> }
                    </IconButton>
                </Box>
                <Divider />
                <List>
                    {menus.user_menu.map((items, index) => (
                        <ListItem key={index} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
                            <ListItemButton component={RouterLink} to={items.link} selected={selected === index} onClick={()=>setSelected(index)}
                                            sx={{
                                                minHeight: 48,
                                                justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
                                                px: 2.5,
                                            }}
                            >
                                <ListItemIcon
                                    sx={{
                                        minWidth: 0,
                                        mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                                        justifyContent: "center",
                                    }}
                                >
                                    {items.icon}
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText
                                    primary={items.header}
                                    sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }}
                                />
                            </ListItemButton>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
                <Divider />
                <List>
                    {menus.sys_menu.map((items, index) => (
                        <ListItem key={index} disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
                            <ListItemButton component={RouterLink} to={items.link} selected={selected === index} onClick={()=>setSelected(index)}
                                            sx={{
                                                minHeight: 48,
                                                justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
                                                px: 2.5,
                                            }}
                            >
                                <ListItemIcon
                                    sx={{
                                        minWidth: 0,
                                        mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
                                        justifyContent: "center",
                                    }}
                                >
                                    {items.icon}
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText
                                    primary={items.header}
                                    sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }}
                                />
                            </ListItemButton>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </Drawer>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Dashboard

```
export const DashboardOutlet = () => {
    return (
        <Box display="flex">
            <SideBar />
            <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1}}>
                <TopBar />
                <Divider/>
                <Container sx={{pt:3}}>
                    <Outlet />
                </Container>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]